How much does "Set" determine "Cat"? (To what extent are "reflective supercategories" unique?)
Definition: Given a category $C$, call a category $A$ (if it exists) ("$A$" for "ambient") a reflective supercategory of $C$ if (1) there is a functor $\iota: C \to A$ that is injective-on-objects and faithful (an "inclusion"), and (2) there is a functor $r:A \to C$ that is a left adjoint to $\iota$ / such that $\iota$ is a right adjoint of $r$. (So $C$, or more properly $\iota(C)$, is a reflective subcategory of $A$.)
Note: for the purposes of this question I don't really care either way whether $\iota(C)$ is a full subcategory of $A$ or not. It is in the motivating example below, so I'm fine with that assumption if it's useful.

Question: Assuming a reflective supercategory $A$ exists for a given category $C$, to what extent is it unique? E.g. what additional conditions can be imposed (if any) to guarantee uniqueness of $A$ (e.g. up to equivalence or isomorphism)? Are there any universal constructions that can take a category $C$ and always return a reflective supercategory of $C$?

Bonus question: What conditions on $C$ would allow us to conclude that at least one reflective supercategory $A$ of $C$ exists?
Motivating example: Given the category $Set$ of "small" sets (proper sets), the category $Cat$ of small categories is a reflective supercategory of $Set$. So answering the above question could answer the question "to what extent does $Set$ characterize $Cat$"?
To clarify, the "inclusion" functor $\iota: Set \to Cat$ associates to each set a small category whose objects correspond to the elements of the set, and whose only morphisms are identity morphisms, i.e. a discrete category. Meanwhile the "reflector" functor $r: Cat \to Set$ sends every small category to the set of all of its connected components. Specifically, the functor sends every object of a given small category to its connected component and sends every morphism of the category to the identity morphism of that connected component (i.e. treating the set of connected components as a discrete category).
Probably this adjunction does not characterize $Cat$ uniquely in terms of $Set$, because if it did that could maybe be used to create a fully formal "ETCC" based on fully formal ETCS. (And apparently no one has every created a fully formal ETCC.)
This related question seems to suggest that $Set$ could have many "reflective supercategories" smaller than $Cat$, so if there is such a characterization of $Cat$ in terms of $Set$, it seems like it would have to be as "the largest reflective supercategory".
"Largest" maybe in the sense that for every reflective supercategory $A$ of $Set$, there is a unique inclusion functor $A \to Cat$ and reflector functor $Cat \to A$ which relates the inclusion functors $Set \to A$, $Set \to C$ and reflector functors $A \to Set$, $Cat \to Set$ respectively.
This doesn't seem completely implausible, to the extent that the "larger" the "ambient category" $A$ of a given category $C$, the more morphisms any candidate "reflector" functor would have to act on while preserving the adjunction, i.e. the more "difficult" it should become to be a "reflective supercategory", so the existence of a universal, "largest" reflective supercategory maybe would not be strange.
Related questions: (1) (2) (3)
Note: a "reflective hull" $B$ of a subcategory $C$ of an a prior already given / fixed "ambient" "supercategory" $A$, $C \subseteq A$, is the "smallest" subcategory of $A$ ("smallest" supercategory of $C$ within $A$), $C \subseteq B \subseteq A$ that is a reflective subcategory of $A$. So a related notion but seemingly not closely related enough to be able to answer this question.
Seems like reflective localization might (???) be one way to generate "reflective supercategories" of a given category $C$, albeit these seem to be "smallest reflective supercategories" with a given property rather than "largest reflective supercategories with a given property".

For $\mathsf{Group}$, given any $\mathfrak{V}$ (a class of groups closed under subgroups, homomorphic images, and arbitrary direct products) determines a reflective subcategory. More generall, if $\mathfrak{V}\subseteq\mathfrak{W}$ are two varieties, then $\mathfrak{V}$ is a reflective subcategory of $\mathfrak{W}$. And given any proper variety $\mathfrak{V}$ (a variety that is not all groups), there are uncountably many varieties $\mathfrak{W}$ with $\mathfrak{V}\subseteq\mathfrak{W}$.

It seems to me the question is ill-posed. You can always artificially adjoin extra objects and morphisms to a category such that the inclusion is an equivalence. If a category has an initial object, you can always adjoin a new initial object (non-isomorphic to the old one), and the inclusion will be a reflective subcategory inclusion that is not an equivalence. By the way, the term "reflective subcategory" requires a full inclusion as part of its definition. Also, "injective on objects" is not a well-behaved categorical notion; see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence

@user43208 "Injective on objects" is well-defined for people who use FOL with equality, which I do. https://mathoverflow.net/a/316660/142698  FOL w/o equality doesn't have any special model theory compared to w/ equality (b/c quotients exist). The "principle of equivalence" isn't well-motivated itself anyway because it doesn't specify any notion of "equivalence" as privileged -- equality is an equivalence too, so why is only that one evil? Seemingly the complaint is about choosing an equivalence in the metatheory to be distinguished by the substitution rule, but again that isn't important.

@user43208 It says in 2nd paragraph of question "Note: for the purposes of this question I don't really care either way whether () is a full subcategory of  or not." And even nLab agrees some sources don't require the full subcategory for the definition, it's not standard.

@user43208 To clarify, "You can always artificially adjoin extra objects and morphisms to a category such that the inclusion is an equivalence." <- the argument here is that, by strengthening the equivalence of categories to an adjoint equivalence, the inclusion defines a reflective subcategory? (cf. theorem 3.3 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence )  "If a category has an initial object, you can always adjoin a new initial object (non-isomorphic to the old one)" <- Doesn't that violate the universal property of an initial object? I.e. how can initial objects not be isomorphic?

@ArturoMagidin If you want the extra reputation, if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

I'll just address the last question with an example. The category with one object (which I'll call $1$) and one morphism has an initial object. Now adjoin a new object (which I'll call $0$) to get a new category, by making $0$ initial (so the new category has just one non-identity morphism $0 \to 1$). The smaller category is a reflective subcategory of the new one. My point is that if $C$ is any category with an initial object, you can perform this adjunction of new initial object $0$ construction, in which $C$ will be a reflective subcategory. Therefore a largest reflective supercategory DNE.

As for the penultimate comment addressed to me, I believe the overwhelming consensus on the definition of reflective subcategory requires fullness, although perhaps you can find older sources that don't reflect this. All I was doing was pointing out this standard; I don't think using terminology idiosyncratically is generally a good idea, but I can overlook this for the sake of the question.

As for the first comment directed at me: I didn't say it wasn't well-defined. Again, I'm just bringing to attention some standard heuristic within the community. The rest of your comment sounds like you want to argue over the point, which I'm not going to do in these comment boxes. If you want to discuss that point, maybe raise a new question?

@user43208 This is helpful, thank you!

I'll go ahead and answer. As to the Bonus Question, I suspect that "most of the time" a category $C$ fully embeds as a reflective subcategory of another category in a nontrivial way (i.e., so that the subcategory inclusion is not an equivalence). An amusing counterexample is the empty category, which has itself as the only reflective supercategory of itself (in either the nontrivial or trivial sense!).
One general thing we can say with regard to the Bonus Question is that if $C$ has an initial object $e$, then we can embed $C$ in a reflective supercategory $D$ by adjoining an extra object $0$ to $C$ in such a way that $0$ is initial in $D$ (so add in precisely one arrow $0 \to d$ for every object $d$ of $D$, and add no others, with composition of morphisms between non-$0$ objects performed as in $C$).
The evident full inclusion $C \hookrightarrow D$ is "injective on objects", a condition OP wants to include. It has a left adjoint that takes $0$ to $e$ [we needed that initial object $e$ because left adjoints preserve initial objects], and acts as the identity on remaining objects of $D$ and morphisms between them. Incidentally, this inclusion is not an equivalence (it is not essentially surjective), i.e., is non-trivial in the sense above.
The same construction shows that for categories $C$ with an initial object (and of course this includes $\mathsf{Set}$) there is no unique "maximal" reflective supercategory $A$. Particularly, there is no maximal reflective supercategory with an initial object, because it could always be extended further by this construction. This gives an answer to the Question, with a particular application toward the Motivating Example.
Of course there are reflective supercategories that are trivial in the sense above, for example, embed any nonempty category $C$ into a larger $D$ so that the inclusion $C \hookrightarrow D$ is an equivalence, just by adding in a spurious extra copy $c'$ of some object $c$ of $C$. Formally, start with the underlying directed graph (aka "quiver") of $C$, adjoin to this graph a new node $c'$ and arrows $i: c \to c'$ and $j: c' \to c$ to get a graph $G$; then on the free (= path) category on $G$, apply the smallest categorical congruence that makes $ij$ and $ji$ congruent to identities, and makes all composites and identities on morphisms between non-$c'$ objects congruent to their evaluations as morphisms in $C$ (see Categories for the Working Mathematician for a general discussion of this type of generators-and-relations approach to constructing categories).
The obvious embedding of $C$ into the category $D$ (whose morphisms are the congruence classes just discussed) is an injective-on-objects equivalence. A left adjoint $F: D \to C$ can be described explicitly: as a functor, it is the identity on non-$c'$ objects, and takes $c'$ to $c$; on morphisms, $F$ takes $i$ and $j$ to $1_c$, and takes each arrow $f$ of $C$ (i.e. each arrow $i(f)$ in the image of the embedding $I: C \to D$) to $f$. The composite $FI$ is the identity functor $1_C$ on the nose. Apply Theorem 3.3 (or actually, its dual) here to create the data of an adjoint equivalence with the identity $FI \to 1_C$ as counit.
This also shows that for any category $C$ there is no maximal reflective supercategory of $C$: you can always extend further by this type of construction. Of course, these "trivial" examples feels like "cheating", even if they meet the OP's conditions. Around this point, a long discussion could be had about the principle of equivalence in category theory, but that may be best left for another time.

Dumb question, but to confirm: the quiver of $C$ initially is "transitive closed", so its free/path category is $C$, but adjoining the new node and arrows to get $G$ generally "breaks transitivity", so this time for $G$ (unlike for the quiver of $C$) we have to explicitly take the free/path category to get back to the realm of categories?

It's something like that, except that I wouldn't say that the free category on the underlying quiver of $C$ is $C$ again, just like I wouldn't say that given a group $G$, taking the free group on its underlying set gets you back to $G$. Anyway, use of language aside, I think you have the intuition.

Anyway this is a great answer, giving two constructions that can be repeated indefinitely (thus showing no "largest" can exist in general), one which preserves equivalence and one that doesn't.

Sorry if I got things off to a bad start, with the words "ill-posed". It's hard for me to find just the right words. The principle of equivalence (which violations of have been dubbed "evil", a term invented by Jim Dolan and meant semi-humorously but often taken amiss) is one of those things that can invite misunderstanding; there's a serious point behind it, but it can take some time to absorb. You may have heard of homotopy type theory and univalence, in which serious effort is made to sort these issues out. Anyway, thanks for your nice words.

I was annoyed because to me personally "categorical" should only mean "defined in terms of categories and functors". (Because functors are the only possible definition that preserves all of the structure of categories.) Of course that includes natural transformations, but to me that should also include properties of categories that are not preserved by equivalence and properties of functors that are not preserved by natural isomorphism. I get that historically the definition of natural transformation came before category and functor, but I don't believe that justifies redefining "categorical".

Okay, it's the beginning of a long conversation and there's a long history behind it. This will sound like name-dropping, but I got to know Mac Lane after moving to Chicago in the 90's (which was like a dream come true, getting to meet one of my heroes), and it may interest you to know that he never quite made his peace with some of these issues. To him, notions like "injective on objects" were perfectly acceptable in the practice. So you may consider yourself in good company :-)
